# Adding x:DataType to page xaml leads to errors in ListView DataTemplate properties

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have set ViewModel from code behind for Dependency Injection. I would like to leave possibility for IntelliSense suggestions in xaml. Everything seems to work, but once I am adding `x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"`, I am getting an error for `Number` property not found and not able to run my solution. Why so and how to fix this?

If I delete `x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"`, everything works fine.

HomePage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.HomePage"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"
             Title=""
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

      <Frame>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label Grid.Row="0"></Label>
          <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TotalData}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <Grid Padding="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Number}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </Grid>
      </Frame>
</ContentPage>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on Jason answer my `HomePage.xaml` should have been:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.HomePage"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"
             Title=""
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

      <Frame>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label Grid.Row="0"></Label>
          <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TotalData}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:DataModel">
                <ViewCell>
                  <Grid Padding="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Number}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </Grid>
      </Frame>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you add

```
x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"
```

to the page, VS assumes that this applies to the entire page.  It is currently not "smart" enough to recognize that there is a templated control in the page that will have a different `DataType`

There are two ways to address this.  One, you can just remove `DataType` entirely.  It is not required, and is just a helper that VS uses to provide Intellisense to the XAML bindings

Alternatively, you can add another `DataType` to your templated controls that tell VS what types are being used for those controls.

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:MyModelClass">
```

you will need to use the correct `xmlns` and class name for your code

Comment: Thank you for answer! Do you mean the one I have added to my original question? Adding suggested part to DataTemplate as I understood, does not work for some reason and gives same errors.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `x:DataType` enables **compiled bindings** which are much faster than traditional runtime bindings. It's not strictly needed, but recommending to remove it entirely is also bad advice without explaining the consequences.

Comment: If it is better to use it. Can you explain how to deal with my current situation? Adding x:DataType to DataTemplate has not solved my issue. Did I get suggested solution wrong?

Comment: because `HomeViewModel` is the **wrong type**.  Whatever the type of `TotalData` is (you don't show that so I can't tell you) should be the type.  If `TotalData` is a `List<Widget>` then `Widget` is the class to use in the `DataType`

Comment: Ahh.. my bad! Now I got it. Maybe that's enough of .Net for today. I am gonna to take a walk