# Why is Simple Binding Not Working on Collectionview in Maui Popup

Tags: binding, popup, maui, collectionview

I am trying to add a Collectionview to a Popup in .Net Maui using very simple binding.
The issue I have is that the binding of the list item property is not recognised to bind to the Label text with the error Error "Binding: Property "PersonName" not found on "BindingTest.Views.PupupPage".
My XAML Page is:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:BindingTest.Views"
             x:DataType="view:PupupPage"
             x:Class="BindingTest.Views.PupupPage">
    <Border
        x:Name="popupBorder"
        BackgroundColor = "LightGrey"
        Stroke ="Black"
        StrokeThickness = "2">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="15" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Border.Shadow>
            <Shadow Brush="Gray"
                Offset="5,5"
                Radius="5"
                Opacity="0.8" />
        </Border.Shadow>
        <Grid
            RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
            <CollectionView
                x:Name="personsList"
                Grid.Row="0"
                SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                           ItemSpacing="5" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding PersonName}"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>

        </Grid>

    </Border>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

And code behind:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
namespace BindingTest.Views;

public partial class PupupPage : Popup
{
    public class SimpleModel
    {
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string PersonEmail { get; set; }
        public RadioButton PersonSelected { get; set; }
    }

    public List<SimpleModel> simpleModels = new();


    public PupupPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;

        PopulateList();

    }

    public void PopulateList()
    {
        SimpleModel person = new SimpleModel() { PersonName = "Person Name"};
        simpleModels.Add(person);

        personsList.ItemsSource = simpleModels;
    }
}
```

If I change {Binding PersonName} to {Binding .} then the there is no error and the model name is shown. It appears the binding is looking for a specific property in PopupPage rather than a property of the collectionview itemsource.

Comment: you need to specify a `x:DataType` for the `DataTemplate`, otherwise it will assume that it uses the same type as its parent (page)

Comment: Excellent, this make perfect sense and works.

Comment: Glad that worked. Similar to this Q&A, so closing this question as a duplicate: [Adding x:DataType to page xaml leads to errors in ListView DataTemplate properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126813/adding-xdatatype-to-page-xaml-leads-to-errors-in-listview-datatemplate-properti)